# ETag is already set - error from Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial, etag

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        AddRequiredInfoToViewBag();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
            Response.Cache.SetETag((Guid.NewGuid()).ToString());
        }
    }
```

The code above crashes when I call an action from a partial View. Does anybody know how to check if ETag is already set in cache?

Comment: Try This :if( filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers["ETag"] == null ) Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347488/httpcachepolicy-setetag

Comment: I did try this, but same error still.
Edit: It is a different question; I'm looking into cache.